# Connecting two or more subnets

Tags: routing, router, subnet

Whether a router is needed to connect two subnets.

Say for example:

```
Subnet-1 : 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.127  Subnet Mask:255.255.255.128
Subnet-2 : 192.168.0.128 to 192.168.0.255 Subnet Mask:255.255.255.128
```

Whether subnet-1 requires a router and subnet 2 requires another router.

Comment: The answers are more useful...Thanks a lot for everyone who shared their ideas.

Comment: Finally can anyone give me a meaningful difference between a vlan and a subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use separate routers for each subnet or you could use one for both. If you would use only one router, there are two ways to go: Router-on-a-stick (both subnets will use or are connected to the same router interface) or connect each subnet to a different interface (remember each router interface should belong to different subnets).

Router-on-a-stick is usually the way to go since routers generally have few interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is required to transit between two networks, whether a 'router' or layer 3 aware switch is better suited to the environment depends on the circumstances of the individual network.

The same routing device can support multiple subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one single Router to connect several IP subnets.

However, you need one Layer 3 interface per Subnet.

To connect the two Subnets you have several options, depending on the topology you're having there.

For example: 
[Layer 2 Switch] <-> [Router] <-> [Layer 2 Switch]
[Server] <-> [Multilayer Switch] <-> [Server]
[Server] <-> [Router] // Connected with one tagged interface
[Server] <-> [Router] // Connected with one cable per Interface / Subnet